# Break react-router routes into own file

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I recently updated my React-Router to v4 and ran into an issue with having my routes inside a separate file. I am trying to keep the code clean and would like to move the routes outside of the index.js. Currently I have it like this in the index.js

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/feature" component={Feature} />
        <Route path="/signout" component={Signout} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
      </App>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
```

While this is okay for a smaller start. Once the project begins to grow this will get very ugly. I tried to break it out into something like

```
const RoutesLib = () => {
    return (
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/feature" component={Feature} />
        <Route path="/signout" component={Signout} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
      </Switch>
    )
};

export default RoutesLib;
```

but when I try and import it there is a ton of errors. Any help would

Comment: can you copy the errors into your question

Comment: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
&& react-dom.development.js:14226 The above error occurred in the <div> component:
    in div (created by App)
    in App
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in Provider

Comment: There is multiple of the first one. Not sure if I am exporting the route file incorrectly but I figure it can't be a component farther down the chain cause it works when they are directly in the index.js file

Comment: Chances are its the way way you're trying to use the RoutesLib component - what does the code that imports and uses RoutesLib look like?

Comment: import { RoutesLib } from './routes'; and instead of the route list I just <RoutesLib />

Comment: `import RoutesLib from './routes'`

Comment: doh. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're making RoutesLib a React Component or a function you need to call to get some JSX. I think what you really want is for it to be a JSX snippet. try this:

```
const RoutesLib = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Welcome} />
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
    <Route path="/feature" component={Feature} />
    <Route path="/signout" component={Signout} />
    <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
  </Switch>
)
```